# Is TCP receiver send duplicated ACK immediately when it receives reordered packet?

Tags: networking, tcp, operating-system

If reordered packet arrived in a short time slot, for example, the packet sequence arrived at receiver is 1, 3, 2, 4, Will the TCP receiver send duplicated ACK immediately? Or if the time slot is small, the kernel or NIC can fix the reordered sequence?

due to my limited TCP/IP stack knowledge, I can't figure it out.

Comment: This should better be asked at [networkengineering.se].

Comment: Generally the receiver will ack every other packet.  So if it aked packet 1 and then receives packet 3 (and fast ack has not be disabled on the socket) then it will send what will be a duplicate ack. If it did not ack packet one, then when it receives packet 3 it will quick ack, but it will not actually be a duplicate ack. Full details are complex.  http://home.simula.no/~paalh/students/MadsJohannessen.pdf is a pretty readable thesis on the subject of tcp performance in the presence of significant reordering.